# Select Dropdown not opening in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

We are working on mobile web browser pages as we have developed a page of customer details where we are let customer select delivery time from dropdown

but this is working fine in desktop web browsers and facing issue when open in mobile web browsers

we cant able to open the dropdown and select options we have tried every ways to open using jquery but still we cant able to open it

before every fields was not accesible so rest we managed to focus the cursor using jquery but only dropdown select we cant able to open

actual issue we already found its conflict of calling js in header file but we cant remove those js which is important in other function

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/ngStorage.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/function.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/animatedModal.min.js"></script>
```

If i remove the  first js `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` then i can able to open dropdown. also i have tried many way like i have replaced the jq`

```
<div class="login-middel">
    <div class="username-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="email payment_email" value="{{takeAwayUser.mst_customer_email}}"> <span id="payment_email_error" class="payments_error"></span></div>
    <div class="username-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Contact" class="contact payment_contact" value="{{takeAwayUser.mst_customer_contact}}"> <span id="payment_contact_error" class="payments_error"></span></div>
    <div class="username-input ">
        <input type="text" placeholder="DD-MM-YY" class="simple_date confirmdate payment_date"> <span id="payment_date_error" class="payments_error"></span></div>
    <div class="username-input" ng-click="getTimeArray()">
        <select class="timepicker confirmtimer payment_time">
            <option>11:30 PM</option>
            <option>12:30 AM</option>
            <option>01:00 AM</option>
            <option>01:30 AM</option>
            <option>02:00 AM</option>
            <option>02:30 AM</option>
        </select>
        <span id="payment_time_error" class="payments_error"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="username-input">
        <textarea placeholder="Remark" class="textarea payment_remark"></textarea> <span id="payment_remark_error" class="payments_error"></span></div>
    <div class="Submit-btn" ng-click="order_payment()">
        <button class="Submit"> PAY <span class="orderPrice">$0.00</span></button>
    </div>

</div>
```

`

this is the HTML content we using. first we were unable to focus even textbox also but somehow using jquery we settled using on click event

This is what we have used to focus and access rest html

```
(function($){
    $.fn.focusTextToEnd = function(){
        this.focus();
        var $thisVal = this.val();
        this.val('').val($thisVal);
        return this;
    }
}(jQuery));

$(document).on("click",'.payment_email,.payment_contact,.payment_date,.payment_remark',function()
{
        $(this).focusTextToEnd();
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a live demo?